# Multiple IP addresses for same host name in /private/etc/hosts?

Tags: mail.app, dns, hosts

I have a corporate mail account (exchange 2007) that uses a self-signed SSL certificate.  No matter what I do, Mail always complains about this when I connect.  If I look at the details it always says the certificate name `post` does not match the dns name I used to connect.

I had the bright idea to add an entry in /private/etc/hosts that mapped the name `post` to the external IP of the server.  This works beautifully and the certificate error is gone and everything works when I am out of the office.

The problem with this is that when I am in the office I need to access the server by its internal address, and the only way I could connect was to remove the line I added to hosts, or to change the IP from the external IP to the internal IP.

Now for the question: Is there a way I can format multiple entries in the hosts file for the same host name, but with different addresses?  I know this is done with `real` dns servers, but it appears not to work in a hosts file.  The idea is for the name lookup to return both IP addresses and Mail will fail over to the second address when the first does not work.

I know there is a setting in Mail for internal and external names for the server, but using this brings back the original certificate errors. After some thought, I also wondered what would happen if I make a second entry for the same name but using IPv6 instead of IPv4?  Should have IPv6 some time later this year, and if I understand correctly you can have one name listed twice in hosts when one address is IPv6.

Comment: You should be able to force mail to accept and store the certificate without the prompt by ticking the box in the 'more details' box.

Comment: Yes, I did that and added the certificate to the local trusted list, but it still complains because the dns name of the server does not agree with the name on the certificate without the hosts entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is no. The hosts file is a static lookup file, and because of this it has no concept of multiple-address per name failover, round-robin, or other features baked into the name resolver.

You can specify multiple names for a given IP address, but not multiple IP addresses mapping back to a single name.

Dare I ask, why can't you access the external interface of the mailserver while internal to your office? We configure all of our clients to use Mail/Jabber externally so they never run into this issue.

Despite conventional wisdom, using the external interface when internally does not "pull all the way across the internet", if configured correctly, of course.

Comment: I second using the external address.

Comment: Something is blocking it because I had to remove the hosts entry to get connected while in the office.

Comment: This is probably overkill, but isn't there a real dns server for osx I could configure in place of the hosts file?  I recall doing something similar on a vista machine where I installed ISC Bind so I could block certain DNS lookups.

Comment: Interesting, apparently BIND is built into OSX. I suppose that's not as big of a surprise as it should be. I found instructions for Leopard, though not necessarily Snow Leopard: http://www.macshadows.com/kb/index.php?title=How_To:_Enable_BIND_-_Mac_OS_X's_Built-in_DNS_Server